# Referenciar duas vezes a mesma tabela em outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A minha questão é a seguinte: Tenho de desenhar um sistema para uma instituição de cuidados de saúde que tem médicos internos.
Existem utentes, e cada utente tem um medico interno. Cada utente tem também médico de família do SNS.

Um medico pode ser medico interno e medico de família, um utente pode ter médicos de tipos diferentes e em algumas situações o mesmo medico pode ser os dois tipos ao utente.

Desenhei a seguinte imagem das opções que me ocorrem. 
Qual acham melhor para implementar? Alguma sugestão diferente das apresentadas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

Comment: Mas todas estruturas parecem ser totalmente diferentes umas das outras, pessoalmente eu iria na primeira `n:m` (muitos para muitos). Mas não dá pra ter certeza de qual o objetivo, pois todas parecem ter propósitos diferentes (ao menos pra mim)

Answer (score 1):

Eu francamente não complicaria tanto e implementava assim: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um médico pode ter vários utentes [check]

Um utente pode ter vários médicos [check]

Um médico pode ser associado a um utente como interno e/ou de familia [check]

Para essa associação usa o campo designacao com os valores (Interno, Familia, Ambos)

E imagina, que o utente necessita cuidados especiais de um médico fora da instituição e que não seja o médico de familia, com este esquema podes facilmente fazer essa associação sem teres de modificar a base de dados!